# Disable specific dates in jQuery datepicker doesn't work perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to disable some dates of array in the datepicker calender. But those dates are not disable in the calender. I have included all the jQuery files needed for the calender.

**scripts**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**html**

```
 <input class="form-control time_slot_searchField" id="datepicker" name="" type="text"  required="" style="">
```

**scripts of disable dates array**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
                  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var day = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
                    return [!~$.inArray(day, exclude) && (date.getDay() != 0)];
                  }
                });
```

Where is the problem. Is there any conflict ?

Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has error at `return [!~$.inArray(day, exclude) && (date.getDay() != 0)];`

Change your code to

```
 var day = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
 return [ exclude.indexOf(day) == -1 ]
```

```js
var exclude = ["2019-06-06","2019-06-25","2019-06-28"]

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var day = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ exclude.indexOf(day) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

 <input class="form-control time_slot_searchField" id="datepicker" name="" type="text"  required="" style="">
```

Comment: ...yes yours one is right....but in my code it is not working...can't find the conflict :(...But I accept your answer